# Why is my front-end not retrieving information from my back-end?

Tags: networking, asp.net-web-api, angular4-httpclient

If I run my application locally (using localhost) it works perfectly.

But when I decided to switch to my global ip address (when I say global I mean not my lan ip address, but the one given by my ISP).

It just doesn't load the data from my back-end.

This is how I make the requests from my front-end:

```
this.http.get("http://my-isp-ip:52899/api/Student/ListStudents").subscribe(response => {
      this.users = response["Users"];
    });
```

And this is how I got my applicationhost.config on my back-end:

```
<bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52899:localhost" />
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52899:my-isp-ip" />
                </bindings>
```

And I run the front-end application like this:
`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`

And I already opened the ports both in my router and my firewall.

Now, in my router I only opened the ports: `4200` since this is the one running on my front-end and `52889` which is the one running on my back-end.

What can I be doing wrong?

Comment: May be try changing this `--host 0.0.0.0` to `--host my-isp`

Comment: I already tried that, and it says that that ip couldn't be bound.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
I changed:

```
<bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52899:localhost" />
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52899:my-isp-ip" />
</bindings>
```

To:

```
<bindings>
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52899:localhost" />
   <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:52899:*" />
</bindings>
```

And run Visual Studio as Administrator...